# how to pass a filename to winston logger?

Tags: node.js, winston

I have winston set up as a logger and it works great.
However, I have several processes that I would like to log to different files. How can I pass the filename into a logger instance?

I am using this as my block

```
'use strict';
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const logDir = '/codeforge/log';

const dailyRotateFileTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  filename: `${logDir}/%DATE%-engine.log`,
  maxSize: "1g",
  maxDays: "3d",
  zippedArchive: true,
  datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});

const logger = createLogger({
  // change level if in dev environment versus production
  level: 'debug', 
  maxsize: '500m',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    // for the log file
    format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console({
      level: 'info',
      format: format.combine(
        format.colorize(),
        format.printf(
          info => `${info.message}`
        )
      )
    }),
    dailyRotateFileTransport
  ]
});

module.exports = logger
```

I would like to pass in a filename to replace the "-engine" part to create or append a log file for it.

thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your logger into a function that you call like

```
const log = require('logger')('myfilename');
log.info('happy logging')
```

Code:

```
'use strict';
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const logDir = '/codeforge/log';

const dailyRotateFileTransport = filename => new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  filename: `${logDir}/%DATE%-${filename}.log`,
  maxSize: "1g",
  maxDays: "3d",
  zippedArchive: true,
  datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});

const logger = function(filename){
  return createLogger({
    // change level if in dev environment versus production
    level: 'debug', 
    maxsize: '500m',
    format: format.combine(
      format.timestamp({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
      }),
      // for the log file
      format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
    ),
    transports: [
      new transports.Console({
        level: 'info',
        format: format.combine(
          format.colorize(),
          format.printf(
            info => `${info.message}`
          )
        )
      }),
      
      dailyRotateFileTransport(filename)
    ]
  });
}

module.exports = logger // is now a function
```

Comment: wow, thanks very much! did not know I could wrap this thusly. Working great !

Comment: How to do it with import logger from 'logger'?

Comment: It seems this code creates a separate file for each calling module. How do I modify this code to use a rotating daily file which combines logs from all the calling modules?

Comment: "I have several processes that I would like to log to different files." was the original question. --- for your case I would just use the modules like normal I would think. (i.e., don't put this code in a separate module)

Comment: Hey @CodyＧ after this logs are not being archived maybe because we are creating a logger instance every time we need to log. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "after this" and "not being archived" ? For each module (file) you should only call require('logger')('name') once. Generally node only creates one instance, but if you want to enforce a singleton then the general node practice (I believe) is to pass the instance along to all the modules requiring it. 
`logFactory = require('logger'); require('./moduleA')({logFactory, ...otherSingletons})`

Comment: Also I'm seeing the answer below... you can just create a dict of previously created loggers with that same name and if it exists return that instance

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **ES6 module** imports, here's a feasible suggestion:

`logger.js`

```js
import winston from "winston";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const { format, transports, createLogger } = winston;
const { combine, timestamp, printf } = format;

export default (meta_url) => {

  const root = resolve("./");
  const file = fileURLToPath(new URL(meta_url));
  const file_path = file.replace(root, "");

  const customFormat = printf(({ level, message, timestamp, stack }) => {
    return `${timestamp} [${level}] ${file_path}: ${stack || message}`;
  });

  const loggerInstance = createLogger({
    level: "info",
    format: combine(
      timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" }),
      format.splat(),
      format.errors({ stack: true }),
      customFormat
    ),
    defaultMeta: { service: "user-service" },
    transports: [
      new transports.File({ filename: "log/error.log", level: "error" }),
      new transports.File({ filename: "log/common.log" }),
    ],
  });

  // Log also to console if not in production
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    loggerInstance.add(
      new transports.Console({
        format: combine(colorize(), customFormat),
      })
    );
  }

  return loggerInstance;
};
```

`server/index.js`

```js
import Logger from "../logger.js";
const logger = Logger(import.meta.url);

logger.info("App running on http://localhost:%i", 5000);
```

**Result:**

```
2021-12-17 15:09:38 [info] /server/index.js: App running on http://localhost:5000
```

***How it works:***

Inside logger.js, instead of immediately returning the logger instance, we return a wrapper function that accepts as argument the file's `import.meta.url`, and then returns the Logger instance.

Inside the logger we simplify the absolute path and we pass it to the custom Logger formats to output. If you don't want to *beautify* the path, simply use `const file_path = fileURLToPath(new URL(meta_url))`

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to create or reinitialize the Logger instance many times, We can check by running

```
DEBUG=winston* yarn start
```

I am using [child logger](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#creating-child-loggers) , here is my logger with typescript,

```
import winston from 'winston';

const { transports, format } = winston;

const { LOG_LEVEL, APP_ENV } = process.env;

const logFormatter = APP_ENV === 'dev'
  ? format.combine(
      winston.format.timestamp(),
      winston.format.colorize(),
      winston.format.printf((meta: any) => {
        const { level, message, timestamp, namespace, stack, ...restMeta } = meta;
        const displayNamespace = namespace ? `[${namespace}] -` : '';
        const stackMessage = stack ? `\n${stack}` : '';
        const otherMetaMessage = Object.keys(restMeta).length > 0 ? `\n${JSON.stringify(restMeta)}` : '';
        return `${timestamp} ${displayNamespace} ${level}: ${message} ${otherMetaMessage}${stackMessage}`;
      })
    )
  : format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), winston.format.json());

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: LOG_LEVEL || 'debug',
  format: logFormatter,
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      silent: APP_ENV === 'test',
    }),
  ],
});

export const Logger = (namespace?: string) => {
  if (namespace) {
    return logger.child({ namespace });
  }
  return logger;
};
```

Usage:
service-abc.js

```
const LOGGER = Logger('service:abc');
export class serviceAbc{
   doSomething(){
      LOGGER.info("do something");
   }
}
```