# Express and winston js the logging is returning undefined or Object with no colorized output

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

I am using winston for logging in express project, with the following script:

At `logger.js`:

```
const {
  createLogger,
  transports,
  format
} = require('winston')


const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: 'app.log',
      level: 'info',
      format: format.combine(format.colorize(),
        format.align(),
        format.timestamp(),
        format.json(),
      )
    })
  ]
});
```

And inside `app.js`:

```
const logger = require('~logger')
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // const reqMsg = {
  //   'Request IP': req.ip,
  //   'Method': req.method,
  //   'URL': req.originalUrl,
  //   'statusCode': res.statusCode,
  //   'headers': req.headers,
  //   'Time': new Date(),
  //   'Response': JSON.stringify(res.send)
  // };
logger.logger.info((req.body))
next();
```

})

What I want to log is each API request data, and it's related response (colorized with timestamp).

The output is as following:

> {"message":"\tundefined","level":"\u001b[32minfo\u001b[39m","timestamp":"2020-07-24T15:44:24.728Z"}

Or:

> {"message":"[Object Object]","level":"\u001b[32minfo\u001b[39m","timestamp":"2020-07-24T15:44:24.728Z"}

I cannot see details of the request/response, and the output is not colorized as expected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to know that a request body only comes on certain HTTP requests (like `POST`, `PUT`, etc), and it is `undefined` when there is no request body.
Secondly, if you are using a body parser (like `body-parser` or the built-in one), `req.body` is an object, and `winston` may have some problems logging objects, so that may be why you can't see the request body when there is one.
Lastly, `winston` colours logs with [ANSI escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), and your terminal (or wherever you're seeing the output) may not be able to render those colours.

To log plain JavaScript objects with `winston`, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090851/winston-logging-object) question.
To view colours correctly, you'll need a terminal that supports ANSI colours (e.g. bash, zsh, and cmd on Windows 10).
And to colourize the **entire** log output, you have to tell the `colorize` function that, like so:

```js
const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: 'app.log',
      level: 'info',
      format: format.combine(
        format.colorize({all: true}),
        format.align(),
        format.timestamp(),
        format.json(),
      )
    })
  ]
});
```

Here is a link to the documentation of the `colorize` function: https://github.com/winstonjs/logform#colorize

Comment: can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76198169/express-and-events-with-winston-logger-set-up-halts-logging-to-file-on-error-occ

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Take-Some-Bytes said, the following middleware function helped me logging everything I need:

```
const logging = require('~logger')
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let oldSend = res.send
    res.send = function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      oldSend.apply(res, arguments)
      logging.logger.info(`Params: ${JSON.stringify(req.params)}, Body: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}, Host: ${req.headers.host}, Route: ${req.originalUrl}, IP: ${req.ip}, Method: ${req.method}`, { ...req.body, status: res.statusCode, data: data })
    }
    next();
})
```